# How to Write a Python program to insert a new item before the second element in an existing array

Tags: python, arrays

all I am learning python from some days back, and please help me to How to Write a Python program to insert a new item before the second element in an existing array

Answer (score 0):

The python list data structure has a insert method associated with it..

The insert method takes two arguments position, value-to-insert.

So for your case it will be something like this.

```
In [1]: l1 =  ['a','b','c','d']

In [2]: l1.insert(1,'x')

In [3]: l1
Out[3]: ['a', 'x', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [4]:
```

We are inserting at index 1, because list index starts with 0.

Comment: Thanks, Arun for the reply I found this https://www.techgeekbuzz.com/python-arrays/ on the internet, the author describes the python array very well.